# clearInterval does not stop setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have 1 button that toggles on and off:
button on -> onrepeat = true
button off -> onrepeat = false

If onrepeat is true, the setinterval to kicks off which it does just fine. If the onrepeat is false, i want it to clear the interval.

My clear interval does not stop the the interval, it just keeps going:

```
 function checkRepeat() {

      var int = setInterval(repeat, 6000);

      if (onrepeat === false) {
          $("#repeat_toggle").attr("class", "repeat_button");

          repeat();
          int;

          onrepeat = true;

      }

      else {

          clearInterval(int);
          $("#repeat_toggle").attr("class", "repeat_off_button");
          onrepeat = false;

       }


  }
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is scoped to the function. It gets reset each time you call `checkRepeat`

You need to scope it to a level above the function.

Comment: if i scope it out, it's going to execute even when the function has not been called, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user1783490 — Put `var int` outside, not `int = setInterval(repeat, 6000);` (that stays inside).

Comment: you can also do console.log( int ) , to get the id of the counter, these ids need to match that is generated by setInerval and passed to clearInterval